# Ubuntu 17.04: Switch to console

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, console

I am used to press Alt-Ctrl-F1 to get a console. This does not work on my machine (ThinkPad T470p) on Ubunut 17.04. Was there a change?

Comment: What key is `Strg` ?

Comment: @George German for Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, playing with the keyboard I found the solution myself:

The new ThinkPad activates the F-keys with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> extension key. Thus to get a console one has to type <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Strange.